# XPath Nested Nodes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml, xpath, nokogiri

I need to loop and get the updates that belong to each lot, but when I use `xmldoc.xpath("//update")` it just gives me all of the updates even if not nested into the lot.  How can I get the updates that are nested in to the selected lot only?

```
lots = xmldoc.xpath("//lot")

lots.each do |lot|
  @lot = Lot.new
  @lot.legacy_id = lot.at("legacy_id").text
  @lot.event = @event
  @lot.group = lot.at("group").text
  @lot.number = lot.at("number").text
  @lot.title = lot.at("title").text
  @lot.description = lot.at("description").text
  @lot.price = lot.at("price").text
  @lot.start_at = lot.at("start_at").text
  @lot.end_at = lot.at("end_at").text
  @lot.position = lot.at("position").text
  @lot.notes = lot.at("notes").text
  @lot.save

  updates = xmldoc.xpath("//update")
  updates.each do |update|
    @lot_update = LotUpdate.new
    @lot_update.save
  end
end
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<event>
    <legacy_id>54321</legacy_id>
    <lots>
        <lot>
            <legacy_id>12345</legacy_id>
            <number>1</number>
            <title>Big Cow</title>
            <description>A big cow</description>
            <position>1</position>
            <price>500</price>
            <start_at>2013-02-15 10:00:00</start_at>
            <end_at>2013-02-15 12:00:00</end_at>
            <group>1</group>
        </lot>
    </lots>
    <lots>
        <lot>
            <legacy_id>12346</legacy_id>
            <number>1</number>
            <title>Small Cow</title>
            <description>A small cow</description>
            <position>1</position>
            <price>500</price>
        </lot>
    </lots>
</event>
```

Comment: Please add an example xml and your expected input/output

Comment: This is the same mistake made in countless StackOverflow questions. I'm sure there are many duplicates. In XPath, `//` does NOT mean "start from here". It means "start from the document root". You want just `update` or `.//update`, depending on whether you're looking for a direct child or any depth.

Comment: I would like to have 1 lot and several updates for each time through.  I tried .//update and it gives me the same output.  It puts all updates in all lots, and just update gives me nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `lot.xpath('.//update')`.

Comment: Or alternatively, `lot.css('update')`. Although this CSS expression does not inherently say "descendants of the current node only" (because CSS cannot say such a thing), the implementation in Nokogiri is that `someElement.css(...)` always looks only at descendants of `someElement`.